# Радио кнопка

Tags: php

ХешКод, здравсвуй! Скажите, вот у меня тут проблемка появилась: есть 2 radio кнопки:

```
<input type="radio" name="good">Положительный<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="good">Отрицательный<br />
```

Так вот, мне надо вставить в базу такое. Если пользователь выбрал первую кнопку, то вставить слово: "Положительный", а если выбрал "Отрицательный", то и в базу вставить то же самое. Однако, я не понимаю, как этих значения запихнуть в переменные?

**P.S в гугле искал и читал, но я всё равно не понял, объясните, пожалуйста.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTML`:

```
<input type="radio" name="good" value="Положительный">Положительный<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="good" value="Отрицательный">Отрицательный<br />
```

`PHP`:

```
$value=$_GET['good']; // если метод - GET
```

Информация из атрибута `value` переносится в переменную. Сообщите, что у вас получится

Comment: Мб $value=$_GET['good']; ?

Comment: Не сработало, просто не добавляет... + у меня не get,а post :)

Comment: evgeniy, отлично, Ваш вариант сработал!! Спасибо большое :)

Comment: Извините, не заметил:)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="good" value="1">Положительный<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="good" value="0">Отрицательный<br />
```

PHP:

```
$value=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['good']);
if($value == 1){$good = 'Положительный';}else{$good = 'Отрицательный';}
```

ну а дальше запрос к БД

Comment: Благодарю.